# React: async and await not working with fetch

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, fetch-api

I have API on Node server returning JSON like this when called:

```
{"result":[{"ProductID":1,"ProductName":"iPhone10","ProductDescription":"Latest smartphone from Apple","ProductQuantity":100}]}
```

I'm trying to display all of that information to user using fetch API with React but no matter what my call returns `undefined`. Here is my React code:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState({})

async function getProducts() {
    await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/listProducts`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response=>{
      setProducts({products:response.result})
      console.log(response.result);
      products.map(products =>
        <h1>{products.ProductName}</h1>
        <h1>{products.ProductDescription}</h1>
        )
    })
    .catch(err=>console.error(err))
  }
```

Function getProducts() is called once when page is loaded. What I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. You need to `return await fetch()` 2. `getProducts` is still going to produce a promise, so you need to consume it as such. Either `await` it or use `getProducts().then()`

Comment: there's also absolutely no need for `async/await` if it's just a wrapper for a `fetch` call. `function getProducts() { return fetch(...); }`

Comment: Wrap this in useEffect and don’t forget to add any dependencies. Also, I think you shouldn’t use .then with async/await as stated in the answer posted. Use one of the other.

Comment: Alright now JSON is successfully printed to console but I'm getting error "cannot read property map of undefined". It might be better to try to display without map-method?

Comment: Looks like you are mapping over products directly after setting state. Until the state is set, the products will be undefined. You need to check for that before expecting them to be there. Or, use useEffect. See my example below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is doing it wrong :

- The name should be `getAndSetProducts` or even `setProducts` / `initProducts` because it returns a `Promise<void>` since you don't actually return anything ;
- You're setting inside `products` an object `{ products: Product[] }`, I think you want only `Product[]` (an array of Products) else you'll have to get products by doing `products.products` ;
- The map is useless, since you don't do anything with the map response, plus the variable `products` in the map overwrite the one imported (may cause some errors later).

Try to do :

```js
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]); // Array instead of object

async function initProducts() {
    await fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/listProducts`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => {
            setProducts(response.result);
            console.log(response.result);
        )
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
}

function getProductsHtml() {
    return products.map(product =>
        <h1>{product.ProductName}</h1>
        <h1>{product.ProductDescription}</h1>
    );
}
```

You can call `initProducts` when component initialize and return `getProductsHtml` inside your jsx render.

Comment: This solved the problem I have fought with a long time, thank you!

Comment: It is my pleasure. Be careful, I've edited my post because I've let the overwrite of `products` variable. Now it's gone.

Comment: This should work but make attention on mixing async/await and promises as in the answer as it may lead to unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 9):

Try this it will work

```
const handleFetchData = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random?client_id=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_UNSPLASH_API_ACCESS_KEY}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
}

useEffect(() => {
    handleFetchData();
},[])
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You may also have a look at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) entry.

Comment: Worked for me. I had no idea you needed to call `await` twice, that's crazy

Comment: Both fetch() and .json() are returning a promise

Answer (score 0):

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAPI = async () => {
            const response = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/listProducts', {
                method: 'GET',
            }).catch((err) => ('Error', console.error(err)));
            const data = await response.json();
            setData(data);
        };
        fetchAPI();
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <ul>
                {data.map((items) => (
                    <li key={items.id}>{items.title}</li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
 const [products, setProducts] = useState({})

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/listProducts')

        // console log here to determine how to set products
      console.log(result)
      setProducts(result)
    }

    fetchData()
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
   if (!!products) {
     // here you could access products!
    }
  }, [products])

  if (!products) return null

  return products.map((product) => (
    <>
      <h1>{products.ProductName}</h1>
      <h1>{products.ProductDescription}</h1>
    </>
  ))
```

Comment: How would I call TestThis function? TestThis() doesn't seem to work

Comment: It’s just an example of what you had. I put it inside component for testing. Just take contents... I’ll update it

Comment: Thanks to you too, I managed to solve it :)

Answer (score -2):

you can't use `async await` with `.then()` you should only use `async await` or `.then()` only

Comment: I have tried without await, the problem is it won't wait for response.

Comment: you absolutely can use `async/await` and `.then` together - although it's often considered bad style. But it's not what the problem is here, the problem is that lack of `return` of the promise returned by `fetch`